# Detecting dark images

Tags: php, css, image-processing, jpeg, image-recognition

We have a large amount of photos coming in on a PHP server every day with varying light conditions and would like to detect if an image is essentially too dark to be of importance. I would start with calculating  the average luminosity of the whole picture, but i don't think this is going to give the best results.

I would like to calculate if an image is too dark AND has no 'detail' at all. If it has 'detail' (E.G. a subject is visible) i would like it to still pass the test. Maybe calculate the difference between the lightest and the darkest pixel??

Is there an algorithm or technique to apply on an image to calculate some sort of 'detail' level?

Comment: Consider using a histogram for the brightness. And with a sobel filter, you can detect the contrast.